# Backup Computer Using Batch Script to external HDD

Tags: batch-file, window, backup

I am looking for a batch script that can detect last modified/accessed/created files in a day
and can copy them to a specified location on external drive.
Also if it can automatically execute just before shutdown
that will also help a lot! Thank You !!

Comment: Check out [Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) if you're on a Windows box.

Comment: I like [FastCopy](http://ipmsg.org/tools/fastcopy.html.en), but I don't have hard numbers for how much better it performs than xcopy or Robocopy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
robocopy \path\to\source \path\to\dest /XO /E /Y
```

or something like

```
fastcopy.exe /cmd=diff /speed=full /force_start /no_confirm_del /auto_close "\path\to\source" /to="\path\to\dest"
```